# Disable Reboot and power off button in Finder ( Yosemite )

Tags: macos, mac

We have implemented an Open Directory on a Mac Mini Server, that is hosted by a third provider. We can connect us with VNC on the Mac Server but the VNC connection success only in the Case that the server is on. If an admin by mistake click on the power off button and turn the server down, we can’t connect any more on the server and need a physical hand, that press on start taste in order to start it. For this service will be very expensive for us.
Question: Can I disable the reboot and power off buttons in Finder on Yosemite, so that this action can only execute from the terminal?

Thank you,
Yannick

Comment: There are methods to change the sleep behaviour to the old-style shutdown/reboot, but nothing can prevent holding the button for 5 seconds from powering it off, it's lower in the system than you can access.

Comment: @Tetsujin It sounds like they're trying to disable the feature within the GUI, not the physical buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those options by unchecking the "Show the Sleep, Restart, and Shut Down buttons" checkbox within Login Options for the specific user that Open Directory is running under the "Users & Groups" System Preferences pane.